# Django URL and making a portion of it optional, but using the same class API View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have this API URL on the back-end and I am wondering how to make a portion of it optional.

```
url(r'^api/documents/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', GetDocumentsAPIView.as_view(), name='documents'),
```

So two things can happen coming from the front-end.

1) When the user logs in, it brings them to the `/home` which lists all of their projects. Clicking on the project brings them `/documents/85` where the number is the number of the project and it lists all the documents for that project. This is sent to the API URL `/api/documents/85`. This much is working fine.

2) The other option is the user will just click on a `Documents` link in the `navbar`, which will just bring them to `/documents`. This should just go to the API URL `/api/documents/` and eventually onto the `serializer.py` where their most recent project is determined and the documents for that are returned and rendered in the front-end

This I can't get working. Not sure if I can do it with just one `url()`, or if I need two. Was hoping the one I posted would look at the `(?P<id>[0-9]+)$` as optional and if nothing was there would return the same `GetDocumentsAPIView`, but this is not the case.

EDIT: Including the view I am using for testing at this point. Just `print()` to see if anything is being routed to the view.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class GetDocumentsAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs.get('id'))
        return Response('Test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you need to add a URL pattern for `r'^api/documents/$'`, which can launch the same view by the way. Only inside the view you'll have to assume `id` is optional:

```py
if kwargs.get('id'):
    # return specific document
else:
    # return list of documents
```

I would rename your first URL pattern to 'view_document' so you can use the name 'documents' on the other, more generic view.

*Note: I think your URL structure is wrong. Reading your URL, according to REST, I would expect to see the `document` with `id` 85 when fetching `documents/85`. If you actually are listing the docs of a project, the URL should be `projects/85/documents/` or if unspecified `projects/documents`.*